# Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have one web application(Asp.net) when I click F5 then got the below issue.

When I try to run the application in VS2015 got the below alert message.

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason:
>   Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1).

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what have you tried so far? Could you provide any piece of code? By now, your quote says it all.

Comment: This question does not provide enough information to help you.  What application?  What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and solve it unchecking the option the Javascript Debugging.

```
    Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

Enable JavaScript debugging for Asp.Net (Chrome, Edge and IE)
```

[image]